# Android Workspace corrupted and lost all projects data

Tags: android, eclipse, file, sdk, directory

I was working on android using eclipse, Last day without any reason All projects closed. When i try to open them, an error occurred, i.e ".Project file is missing".

I change the work space and copy all files to new workspace and then try to import but not work.

when i see the files inside my projects folders, all files are of size 0 kb. mean all data from all files got deleted.

Is there any way to restore that project files??? I was working on My Final Year project from the last 2 months and again goes to same start state. Please help me if there is any way to recover. Thanks

Comment: System Restore .. if you're using Windows maybe?

Comment: In eclipse You can find Local History....  you have an option

Comment: Backup your workspace!  then add the missing .project file for each project one by one. they arent that hard to create by hand since they are just simple xml files... you can get a good example by creating a new android projec for editing/restoring.

Comment: Yes, Most of the time i take backup, but what can i do now when lost everything